# IE 7 - CSS Banner positioning problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

This only happens in IE7 - I lose my menu items on the top.

My banner is being forced to the top - rather than sitting below the top nav.

Any clues on how to force this to sit in the correct place in IE7?

http://www.jacksonenterprises.co.nz/

Comment: unfortunately I can't run IE now, but try adding position:absolute to the style, and then positioning it accordingly. And if you can't solve it, you can always apply alternative styling just for IE 7 via HTML conditional statement...

Answer (score 0):

div.header has height 25 px. Remove this attribute or calculate it properly.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things to take note of, make sure your slider is not absolutely positioned. If it is, make sure there's enough margin at the top.

Secondly, your header div only has a height of 25px applied to it, despite it having a logo and a navbar floated underneath it. I see you're using a 'clear:both' trick, which is good - but IE7 will only respect it as long as the height is correctly set.

So in sum, use the following code to fix your CSS in line:

```
div.header {
height: 145px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, something so simple that I was overlooking.  This fixed it!

Comment: No probs, glad we could help :)